# ODBCDataReader very slow

Tags: c#, .net-core, odbc

The following basic code takes about 35 seconds to complete the `dt.load(reader)`.  The database is a MS Access .mdb database with about 210 "columns" and maybe 37 rows.

I've seen many blogs and posts about this where "its slow" "is there another way" etc etc. This is only 200 or so rows... maybe 1 sec tops, right?

```
string connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=" + file;
_conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

string sql = "select * from fields";

OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql, _conn);
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Load(reader); // 30+ seconds to complete

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    ...
```

Also tried the below... same 35 seconds delay on `Fill()`

```
        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Clear();

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: What speed is it when you only select 1 row "SELECT * FROM fields TOP 1", what speed is it when you only select 1 column "SELECT Id FROM fields".

Comment: sorry, updated OP... its 210 columns and 37 rows. I'll check a single row though.

Comment: 2300 ms for top 1 and 53 ms for top 1 single column

Comment: I'm tempted to say, use a 'modern' database format, but I presume this is a legacy app that you can't update ?

Comment: Exactly.  Migration of access databases to SQL Server via .netcore ODBC

Comment: If it's migration, does it matter about being slow.  You are only going to do it once.

Comment: @Neil Its not a single database.  There's hundreds of user databases that "users" will link to and migrate in.  At this speed, another table that has 10,000 rows will take over an hour for just that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this and it corrected my issue!  Amazing results now... 327 milliseconds including overhead for the EF.core method calls in the same call (destination connection).

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/my-solution-to-access-being-slow-with-odbc/a5a6522f-a70f-421e-af1b-48327075e010

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Access is much slower when multiple users are accessing the database.  Make sure your app isn't connected and check for a .ldb file in the access directory.  If it is there, someone else has it open (or crashed out, leaving locks).
If so, try the compact and repair option in the menu. (By default it runs this when the last person exits the database, but if someone crashes out the database never gets compacted).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Its just a standalone .mdb and no one is using it but me locally.  I dont even have access installed, just the drivers to open it... Access 2016 drivers

Answer (score 1):

Access is a front end database, meaning that tables are essentially passive - little different than a csv file in a sense.

Access does have a 255 field max so at 210 you are approaching that - and while perhaps that is an issue, you could test a lower field count to be sure - but I doubt that it is.  Record set queries run fast.  Running a select query within Access for this table would execute in the blink of an eye - - but you are setting up a connection outside of Access it appears - so where does this code sit.. that is invoking  the ODBC reader?   Would this same connection code be faster if aimed at a different data set format other than an Access mdb? ….

Comment: I'l have liked to see the speed of the migration that occurs when I import Access databases into SQL Server directly.  The whole database with 12 tables is imported into a new db shell in 60 seconds tops.  I think that uses OleDb/Jet not ODBC.